# Merge Tags: workload and workload-distribution

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

The [workload](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/workload) and [workload-distribution](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/workload-distribution) tags each have only a handful of questions. The latter seems like an unnecessary specification. Even if we were to define them differently, I expect most users would still pick one at random.

I suggest that all questions under [workload-distribution](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/workload-distribution) be merged into [workload](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/workload) and that the distribution tag be deleted.

Comment: This has been up for almost a week, with 9 upvotes and no downvotes. It looks to me like there won't be a lot of discussion here. Do you want to ping a moderator and ask him to merge?

Comment: @StephanKolassa Dropped a link in the chat, I'll ping a mod directly later if no one picks it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went ahead and merged this, like Stephan was saying no one was really disagreeing and it seems a good idea.